# OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, p2p

I have written a client and a server-side code to set a P2P type system with a server as a middleman to distribute a file to N clients.

I am getting this error OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied in this chunk of my code on the server side

```
try:
        for i in l:
            print(i)
            x = random.randint(0,N-1)
            print(x,"Index")
            serverSocketTCPRequest = serverSocketTCPList[x]
            serverSocketTCPRequest.settimeout(2)
            serverSocketTCPRequest.connect((i[0],i[1]))
            serverSocketTCPRequest.send("SEND".encode())
            serverSocketTCPRequest.send(str(chunkID).encode())
            data = serverSocketTCPRequest.recv(1024)
            serverSocketTCPRequest.close()
            b = False
            return data
    except Exception as ex:
        print(traceback.format_exc())                
        time.sleep(1)
        # print(l)
        pass
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\IITD\5th Sem\COL334\Assignment 2\server.py", line 149, in getChunks
    serverSocketTCPRequest.connect((i[0],i[1]))
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
Traceback (most recent call last):

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\IITD\5th Sem\COL334\Assignment 2\server.py", line 198, in sendChunkRequest
    checkMessage, serverAddress = serverSocketUDPRequest.recvfrom(1024)
socket. Timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\IITD\5th Sem\COL334\Assignment 2\server.py", line 149, in getChunks
    serverSocketTCPRequest.connect((i[0],i[1]))
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

My client side code for the same is

```
def handleTCP(client:Client):
global N
while(True):
    try:
        # print(clientList.index(client), client.clientSocketTCPRequest.getsockname())
        client.clientSocketTCPRequest.listen(2*N)
        client.clientSocketTCPRequest.settimeout(2)
        connectionSocket, addr = client.clientSocketTCPRequest.accept()
        print("Connected")
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
        if message.decode() == "SEND":
            i = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
            connectionSocket.send(client.dict[int(i)])
            connectionSocket.close()
        elif message.decode() == "GET":
            i = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
            client.dict[int(i)] = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            connectionSocket.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
        m = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
        print(m,client.clientSocketTCPRequest.getsockname())
        # print(traceback.format_exc())
        continue
```

I can't think of a reason this is occurring. The client side shows just a timeout error on each of the N ports.

I have attached the entire [client](https://github.com/harshitmawandia/COL334-A2/blob/master/client.py) and [server](https://github.com/harshitmawandia/COL334-A2/blob/master/server.py) side codes and the [file](https://github.com/harshitmawandia/COL334-A2/blob/master/A2_small_file.txt) I'm trying to send.

Comment: `for i in l` -- so what is in `l`?

Comment: An invalid argument was supplied. Did you try printing the arguments to `connect`?

Comment: l is a list of clientAdresses

Comment: Yeah, I tried printing the arguments, It seemed correct, it was a list of clientAddresses